# Android Gradle не работают зависимости

Tags: android, gradle

Получил на поддержку приложение и вот всплыла проблема, при добавлении dependencies новый функционал не подключается, хотя ничего красным не подчеркнуто и sync после добавления проходит нормально. Просто не появляются нужные классы.
В данном случае пробовал подключить Yandex метрику, но с другими плагинами тоже проблемы.
Зависимости которые ранее были подключены в приложении работают нормально, сложность только что бы новое добавить.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ru.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionName "1.0.1"
    versionCode 31
}



packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }
}
productFlavors {
    phone {
        applicationId 'ru.app'
    }
    tablet {
        versionName defaultConfig.versionName + "-tablet"
        versionCode = defaultConfig.versionCode + 1
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile project(':baseapp')
compile project(':basegcm')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:2.30'

}
```

Вот еще содержимое baseapp

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:0.9.9'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.2'
compile project(':basenetwork')
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'

}
```

Comment: А пробовали после подключения ребилд сделать? У меня тоже иногда новые зависимости видится перестают, но ребилд обычно помогает.

Comment: Да помогло. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Решение простое, спас ребилд после добавления зависимости.